# Ayuda con ejercicio de condicionales en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito ayuda con este ejercicio, estoy trabado y no logro resolverlo

Escribí la función puedeJubilarse que recibe por parámetro la edad, el sexo y además, los años de aportes jubilatorios que posee una persona, tené en cuenta que el mínimo de edad para realizar el trámite para las mujeres es de 60 años, mientras que para los hombres es 65. En ambos casos, se deben contar con al menos 30 años de aportes jubilatorios.

```
function puedeJubilarse(edad, fem, mas, aportes){
return (edad == "fem" >= 60 && aportes >= 30) || (edad == "mas" >= 65 && aportes >= 30);
}
```

Comment: ¿Pero cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: @fedorqui Asumo que es hacer que ese código, que no tiene mucho sentido tal y como está, funcione. "Compila" por la *coerción de tipos* de JS, pero cualquier *Lint* mostraría avisos de que algo está mal

Answer (score 4):

Si modificar los parámetros de tu función, podrías escribir algo como

```
function puedeJubilarse(edad, fem, mas, aportes) {
  return aportes >=30 && ((fem && edad >=60) || (mas && edad >=65));
}
```

Que se puede leer como "puede jubilarse **si** los aportes son mayores a 30 y se cumple que

- el sexo es femenino y la edad es mayor a 60

ó

- el sexo es masculino y la edad mayor a 65.

Pero realmente, siempre que `mas` sea `true`, `fem` debería ser `false`, y viceversa (son excluyentes), con lo que podrías tener un único parámetro que fuera el sexo:

```
function puedeJubilarse(edad, sexo, aportes) {
  return aportes >=30 && (edad >=65 || (sexo = 'mujer' && edad >=60));
}
```

Si te fijas, no miro si el sexo es 'varón' porque no es necesario, asumo que sólo hay dos posibilidades y si no es una, forzosamente debe ser la otra.

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada evita cambiar el valor directamente de un atributo de una función, ya que esto puede afectar la referencia principal a otra variable, por otro lado deseo darte una recomendación para que la puedas aplicar a futuros proyectos, y es utilizar algo llamado identación.

Esto no es nada mas que separar el código a una determinada "sangria" digamoslo así, de 5 espacios normalmente, esto se puede hacer con el tabulador si te encuentras en un IDE, aquí en esta pagina no es posible.

un ejemplo con tu código:

```
function puedeJubilarse(edad, fem, mas, aportes){

     return 
     (edad == "fem" >= 60 && aportes >= 30) || 
     (edad == "mas" >= 65 && aportes >= 30); 

}
```

Lo cual lo hace mucho mas legible, que por cierto si usas una sangría a cinco espacios o mas en esta herramienta, veras que cuando publiques el código se publicara como un "bloque de código", esto lo hace mas facil de leer para aquellos que deben ayudarte, también para evitar tener que dar cinco espacios a cada linea de código.

Lo que puedes hacer es pegar primero todo tu código aquí y luego seleccionarlo, despues darle al icono ({}), del recuadro que te aparece a la hora de hacer una pregunta, esto acomodara automaticamente todo tu código a una sangria de 5 espacios.

Dicho esto, analizando bien tu función podrías acortarla un poco teniendo solamente 3 parametros, el primero la edad, el segundo el sexo y el tercero aportes.

Lo otro es que deberías hacer condicionales separados, ya que necesitas comparar varias cosas:

```
function puedeJubilarse(edad, sexo, aportes){

     let puedeHacerlo = false;
     if(sexo == "masc"){

          if(edad >= 65){

               if(aportes >= 30){

                    puedeHacerlo = true;

               }

          }

     }else if(sexo == "fem"){

          if(edad >= 60){

               if(aportes >= 30){

                    puedeHacerlo = true;

               }

          }

     }

     return puedeHacerlo

}
```

como puedes ver, el código termina siendo una función bastante larga de esta manera, sin embargo entender el código es simple:

la variable puedeHacerlo la iniciamos dentro de la función con un valor de false, (Este valor no cambiara si no se cumple ninguna de las condiciones), lo cual requerimos, esta la usaremos luego para saber si la persona cumple o no con las condiciones dadas para pensionarse.

por otro lado hacemos luego lo siguiente:

primero comprobamos si la persona es de sexo masculino, si es así entramos a otra condición y preguntamos ahora si la edad >= 65 años, si es así entramos a otra condición y preguntamos por ultimo si los aportes son mayores o iguales a 30 años, en caso de que todas estas condiciones se hallan cumplido al pie de la letra, cambiamos el valor de la variable puedeHacerlo a true.

De otra manera, si alguna de estas condiciones no se cumplió, entramos a otro ciclo de comprobaciones, esta vez comprobaremos si la persona es mujer, de ser así comprobamos si su edad es mayor o igual a 60 años, si es así entonces comprobamos por ultimo si también ha hecho un aporte mayor o igual a 30 años, si es así cambiamos el valor de la variable puedeHacerlo a true, en caso de que alguna de estas comprobaciones no se halla cumplido, entonces el valor de la variable puedeHacerlo simplemente no cambiara, es decir, (seguirá siendo false), luego retornamos el valor.

Sin embargo si deseas un ejemplo un poco mas avanzado y corto de esta función puedes usar algo llamado shorthand if, que es la "version corta" de los condicionales:

```js
function puedeJubilarse(edad, sexo, aportes){

     let puedeJubilarse = 

          sexo == "masc" && edad >= 65 && aportes >= 30 ? true :
          sexo == "fem" && edad >= 60 && aportes >= 30 ? true : false;

     return puedeJubilarse;

}

console.log(puedeJubilarse("masc",61,31));
```

El funcionamiento de shorthand if lo puedes investigar mas a fondo si lo deseas, sin embargo daré una explicación básica de su funcionamiento:

primero va la variable a la que queremos asignarle un valor dependiendo de unas condiciones:

```
let puedeHacerlo
```

después pones un igual (para que pueda ser almacenado ese valor en la variable dependiendo de el resultado que devuelvan las condiciones):

```
let puedeHacerlo =
```

y apartir de aquí van las condiciones, en este caso devolverán valores de tipo boolean, es decir valores que pueden ser ya sea true o false, ningún otro estado (OJO, esto es porque estamos usando booleans para el ejemplo). pero perfectamente puedes hacer que se almacene otro tipo de valor dependiendo de las necesidades del usuario. un ejemplo de una condición simple es la siguiente:

```
let puedeHacerlo = 5 > 4 ? true : false;
```

entonces nos dice que si 5 es mayor a 4 el valor que almacenara la variable será true, ¿Es esto cierto?, ¡Pues si!, cinco es mayor a 4, por lo que almacenara true, de lo contrario si 5 fuera mayor a 4 almacenaría false.

**recordar que: el signo (?), funciona como un if, mientras que el signo (:) en un shorthand if funciona como un else.**

Explicado un poco como funciona un shorthand if, el código escrito es exactamente el primer código largo que viste, solamente que reducido a un shorthand if, (Es decir comprobamos lo mismo y hacemos exactamente lo mismo que en la otra función), pero con menos lineas de código.

Answer (score 0):

```
function puedeJubilarse(edad, genero, aportes) {
  return aportes >= 30 && ((genero == 'M' && edad >= 65) || (genero == 'F' && edad >= 60));
}
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Si bien el código proporcionado puede que responda a la pregunta, deberías de incluir el porque lo hace. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].